# Render static html page inside my base django template

Tags: html, django, apache, django-staticfiles

I'm developing a web portal using
 - Django 1.2
 - Apache
 - Mod WSGI

I've several HTML files which are being served by apache.

I want to render those static HTML pages under my base template in order to keep my header / footer and dynamic menus intact.

One way I could thought its using iframes. Another way is to do read HTML files and return string while rendering but in that case I'm loosing advantage of apache, so I want to know if there would be any better way of doing it, is there any existing solution provided by django stuff ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but you can insert an html file (or even another template) in a template with the [`ssi`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-ssi) and [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) tags, depending on your needs:

```
{% ssi '/path/to/file.html' %}
{% include 'relative/path/to/template.html' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include)

> Loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a way of "including" other templates within a template.

it's as simple as

```
{% include "templates/static_template_1.html" %}
```

or, if you create a variable in the view side:

```
{% include template_name_variable %}
```

it shares the context with the base template (the one including them)

Comment: {% include %} is intended to insert another templates. shahjapan wants to insert static files. {% ssi %} is better for that, since it doesn't parse the files before inserting them.

Comment: whoops. i read "html templates", probably because it's been a while since last time i used 100% static files. yes then, ssi is way better! @shahjapan keep my answer for reference just in case you'll have to use templated files and not statics!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

*Perhaps you ment to load html-files outside the template-system. Then my way will not suffice.*

An option is to extend your base template.

Your base template should not be aware of the sub templates as that would be logically wrong.

Example:

**base_template.html:**

```
<html>
<div id='header'></div>
{% block content %}
    This text can be left out else it it will shown when nothing is loaded here
{% endblock %}
```

**sub_template.html:**

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>This is my subpage</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

You can read more here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/